# Netbeans property sheet Swing control in a container from Navigator window

Tags: java, swing, layout, netbeans, border-layout

While the JButton has a Layout category from the Properties sheet, the other components do not.  Specifically, the JList is part of a JScrollPane which is, apparently, unclickable.

How do I select the JScrollPane to edit its direction property?

In the Netbeans GUI builder, the following code is auto-generated and isn't editable:

```
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
jList2 = new javax.swing.JList();
jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

jButton1.setText("jButton1");
add(jButton1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

add(jScrollPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
    String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
    public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
    public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
});
jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList1);

add(jScrollPane2, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

jList2.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
    String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
    public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
    public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
});
jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jList2);

add(jScrollPane3, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_END);

jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
    }
));
jScrollPane4.setViewportView(jTable1);

add(jScrollPane4, java.awt.BorderLayout.LINE_START);
}// </editor-fold>
// Variables declaration - do not modify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the panel you want to modify, in the `PropertySheet`, scroll down to the `Layout` category.  From there, modify the `direction` property.

Comment: curious, there's a Layout category for the JButton, but not for the JList or other other controls.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Is the JList in a scroll pane?

Comment: yes.  I updated the question.  can't seem to click the JScrollPane.

Comment: Yeah, that can be a pain.  You need to select the scroll pane from the navigator